# Setting Up a Selenium-WebDriver Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I would like to automate Firefox using Java (and eclipse) through a Selenium-WebDriver project.

I am also following the directions at http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#setting-up-webdriver-project.

I have created a Selenium folder in c:/Java/Selenium.

However, nothing happen (not Maven installation) when I try to the following :

> from a command-line, CD into the project directory and run maven as
>   follows.
>
> mvn clean install

Below is the content of my pom.xml (I am not sure about what version to be equally updated).

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.42.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Your running the `mvn clean install` from which directory?

Comment: From the Selelium folder I created.

Comment: Anyway, I am going to focus on my first chose which is the use of pure java libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not your specially asked. But I think this is the easiest way to set up the selenium project.

http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/profiles/blogs/selenium-2-0-webdriver-how-to-configure-selenium-webdriver-in

It will open you a firefox and you can do everything you want.
You only need the selenium libaries and firefox path:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Users\\your_user\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}
```

its not in the example but its need.